# Can't get sprite position

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I have somewhere in my code something that I have done so many times, but now I can't!

```
for (b2Body* bo = world->GetBodyList(); bo; bo = bo->GetNext()) 
    {


      CCSprite *tempSprite = (CCSprite *) bo->GetUserData();
        NSLog(@"%f",tempSprite.position.x); //crashes in this line.
```

I am counting the bodies on my world and I can see i have 22 of them, but every time i try to do somthing with: `tempSprite.position.x` it crashes!

I can also print this:

```
 if(tempSprite != NULL)
            NSLog(@"YES");
```

Why can't I get the position?
My world is working great; the contact listener is doing just fine; can't understand that.

any help ?

Comment: the EXC_BAD EXCESS that you cant never know what is that . but everything i do that is contain the tempSprite.position is working.

Comment: What did you put in the body user data with SetUserData?

Comment: spriteBodyDef.userData = spriteName; as usual .. how can i even debug it ?

Comment: Um... and what type of variable is 'spriteName'?

Answer (score 0):

solved but not clearly why

i did

```
        [badBondSheet1 removeChild:actora cleanup:YES];
        [self removeChild:actorb cleanup:YES];
        [self shiftEnemies:touchPointA]; // calls the code that i have posted
```

when shiftEnemies is the function that i have posted-that runs on all the bodies.

i have corrected to:

```
       [self shiftEnemies:touchPointA];
    [badBondSheet1 removeChild:actora cleanup:YES];
    [self removeChild:actorb cleanup:YES];
```

and it works.

that was because i was running over my bodies, which some of them didnt have a userData, because i already cleaned up the sprite !

so you have to destroy body and clean the sprite and then run over your bodies.
**conclusion: DO NOT CLEAN YOUR SPRITE, AND DO SOMETHING ELSE BEFOR YOU DESTROY YOUR BODY !**

sounds reasonable ?

Comment: It sounds like you are destroying the thing you put into the body's user data, in which case you should SetUserData(NULL) for that body to make sure it doesn't keep an invalid reference.

Comment: @iforce2d i cant understand . i i destroy a body first, and also its sprite, and then i am running over my bodies, that body does not exist anymore, so its userdata is not relevant cause i am not even check it- he already outside my world ! so what did you mean by your answer ?

Comment: ok got it ! i destroy the body AFTER i call that function so there is still a body in the list but it has no sprite userData. thanks a lot you where right !